# javascript/jquery как сделать inline-скрипт, который будет заменяться результатом выполнения скрипта?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пример:

```
<div>
Стоимость акций на текущий момент: <script>тут ajax запрос, который получает данные и заменяет этот скрипт этими данными</script>
</div>
```

Comment: и в чем смысл сего? по сути вам надо получить даныне и вставить в определенное место. Зачем при этом в это место изначально пихать скрипт, и потом пытаться его убрать? сделайте там `<span id="cost">` и в конце документа добавьте свой `$(function(){  $("#cost").load("path/to/script.php")})`

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт - отдельно, а в этом месте ссылка которая при клике будет заменяться данными, пришедшими с сервера:

```html
<div>Стоимость акций на текущий момент: <span class="result"><a href="#" class="link">узнать</a></span></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      cashe: false,
      type: 'post',
      url: 'result.php', //здесь путь к php-скрипту, который у Вас возвращает стоимость акций
      success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
      }
    }); 
});
</script>
```